# Firebase Storage very slow compared to Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-hosting

Anyone know why firebase storage would be so ridiculously slow compared to firebase hosting?

**Results**

- Time to download image of firebase hosting: `16ms`
- Time to download same image from firebase storage: `2.23s (2.22s is TTFB)`
- Time to download same image from firebase storage (Asia Pacific Region): `1.72s (1.70s is TTFB)`
- (File size: 22.7kb / jpeg / firebase storage has read open to everyone)

This is repeated over and over in tests. Is there any way to speed this up to a decent time, or is firebase storage unusable for small files (images/thumbs)?

**For Comparison**

- S3 North Cal - approximately `500ms`
- S3 Asia Pacific - Approximately `30ms`
- Cloudinary - Approximately `20ms`

**Extra info:**

- I am based in Australia.
- Exact same files. Always images under 100kb.
- The slow down is always in the TTFB according to dev tools.
- Hosting URL: https://.firebaseapp.com/images/thumb.jpg
- Storage URL: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/.appspot.com/o/thumb.jpg?alt=media&token=

Comment: So currently there are really no option to use firebase storage for photos with reasonable downloading time? It's about 10 times slower than getting photo from my ftp server (10$ per year). It's difficult to believe that such a big service like firebase has that kind of problem. I found that here https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/ I can set every photo to have a public link and then getting photo from that public link is blazing fast (about 50ms). So now the question is: is there any way to make every uploaded photo public?

Comment: Makin every photo public is now available, using the GUI in cloud console.

Answer (score 23):

I found the solution.

If you have your files already uploaded to storage go to: https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser?project=your_project > pick your bucket > select all interesting files and click Make public (or something similar - I'm not english native).

To have all new uploaded files public by default you need to install Google cloud SDK (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/) and from your command line use the following command for your bucket:

`gsutil defacl set public-read gs://your_bucket`

After that all my current and new images are available here storage.googleapis.com/my_project.appspot.com/img/image_name.jpg
and downloading time is definitely shorter.

Comment: Thanks for giving me this hint!

Comment: the documentation for sharing storage data publicly: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console?#_sharingdata

Comment: we should accept this answer, this is the best answer I got

Comment: It's not a solution since most people don't want to make their files public

Comment: Thanks, it works well for Firebase Storage with `gsutil acl ch -u AllUsers:R gs://project.appspot.com/filename.json`. Load time has been decreased from 550ms vs 30ms in average.

Comment: do the storage rules on firebase still apply?

Comment: For my application it is still extremely slow... has anybody else still the issue after making the bucket public?

Answer (score 2):

Hosting = Storage + CDN, so really what you're seeing is you hitting a CDN near you, rather than going directly to the GCS or S3 bucket. Same is true with Cloudinary/Imgix. This is why performance is so much better for Hosting than Storage.

Addressing the issue of TTFB being so different between AWS and GCP: unfortunately this is a known issue of GCS vs S3 (see [this great blog post](http://blog.zachbjornson.com/2015/12/29/cloud-storage-performance.html) w/ in depth perf analysis). I know this team is working to address this problem, but going the "stick a CDN in front of it" route will provide a faster solution (provided you don't need to restrict access, or your CDN can authorize requests).

Note: GCP has announced a Sydney region ([announcement blog post](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/09/Google-Cloud-Platform-sets-a-course-for-new-horizons.html)) to be launched in 2017, which might help you.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I ended up putting fast.ly in front of my storage bucket. 

Would be great to have a CDN/Fastly as a paid addon to save the hassle!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Ziwi answer.
I think it is also ok to change rules directly in Firebase

```
// Only a user can upload their profile picture, but anyone can view it
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/<bucket>/o {
    match /users/{userId}/profilePicture.png {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

The source is https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/07/5-tips-for-firebase-storage.html

[image]