# Accessing Files from Firebase Storage vs Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-hosting

So here is the scenario:
**When I access files from Firebase Storage:**

1. I get my file from **storage bucket**(.html, .png, .zip etc) (Small in size btw no more than 2mb).
2. Store that file in my local storage so the app don't need to download it again and consume the bandwidth of the server.
3. Use it from local storage everytime the app needs it.

**When I access files from Firebase Hosting:**

1. I get my file from nearest **CDN of Firebase**(.html, .png, .zip etc) (Small in size btw no more than 2mb).
2. Store that file in my local storage so the app don't need to download it again and consume the bandwidth of the server.
3. Use it from local storage everytime the app needs it.

**NOTE:** I also have one file `version.txt` on storage bucket (Firebase Storage). According to the value in this file, I decide whether to fetch file in Step 1 again or not. It means the `version.txt` is fetched everytime.

**Questions:**

1. How to achieve the similar version programming part in Firebase Hosting? I know we deploy folders, can we get their version from Firebase CDN. If yes, how?
2. In which method I gonna first hit my **LIMIT** as we know Firebase is paid after a limit.

**Pros of Hosting:**  It will be faster. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851742/firebase-storage-very-slow-compared-to-firebase-hosting)

**PS:**
 1. My concern is bandwidth and not security.

2. Currently, I am using basic Plan (free) with limits [Source](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/):

[image: Hosting Plan Details]
[image: Storage Plan Details]

Answer (score 7):

From the Firebase docs:

- The [Firebase Realtime Database](http://firebase.google.com/docs/database) stores JSON application data, like
  game state or chat messages, and synchronizes changes instantly
  across all connected devices.
- [Firebase Remote Config](http://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config) stores
  developer-specified key-value pairs to change the behavior and
  appearance of your app without requiring users to download an update.
- [Firebase Hosting](http://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) hosts the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript for your website
  as well as other developer-provided assets like graphics, fonts, and
  icons.
- [Cloud Storage](http://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) stores files such as images, videos, and audio as well as other user-generated content.

Storage has higher free tier limits, while Hosting might be a little faster. Note that all files on Hosting are publicly accessible, so if you need authentication or authorization, you should use Storage.

Comment: My main concern is bandwidth not the authentication. Then which one should be used?

Comment: If the images comes from user input, how can firebase hosting be used since you need to re deploy each time ? @Mike McDonald

Comment: If I have images loaded in Google Storage, and I want to display them on a static html page, how would i do so?

Comment: `<img src="https://firebasesstorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/{bucket}/o/{object}?token=12345"` would be my recommendation (or use the GCS media link URL and ensure the object is public)