# Firebase Storage very slow to respond

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The time to download an image from firebase storage: 2.59s

[image]

Is there any way to speed this up to a decent time, or is firebase storage unusable for small files (images/thumbs)?

My project:

https://beach-real-estate.vercel.app/

update---

my firestone rules:

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // Listings
    match /listings/{listing} {
        allow read;
      allow create: if request.auth != null && request.resource.data.imgUrls.size() < 7;
        allow delete: if resource.data.user == request.auth.uid;
      allow update: if resource.data.user == request.auth.uid;
    }
   
    // Users
    match /users/{user} {
        allow read;
        allow create;
        allow update: if request.auth.uid == user
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you choose for the firebase server location? It might just be lag? I've never experienced load times like that using firebase, unless it was for large files.

Comment: It is my first project with firebase/google cloud. I don't know where this configuration is, I searched on google but I couldn't find it. Is this configuration in the google cloud console?

Comment: Do I have to install gcloud CLI?

Comment: Login in to the firebase console and look at project settings, you should see Default GCP resource location. This can affect response times but I don't know to what degree...

Answer (score 1):

Firebase storage is basically a bucket within GCP. If you want to have faster download times, you should make your files publicly available.

If you need a guide for that, use [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets)

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851742/firebase-storage-very-slow-compared-to-firebase-hosting) that may help you.

Comment: I configure as the guide says and add this command in the CLI: gsutil defacl set public-read gs://my-house Nothings happens https://imgur.com/eg1RiWX

Comment: I set the region too.